# Jailbroken using yalu102 without Cydia and can't install Cydia because "already jailbroken"

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, cydia

I recently jailbroke my iOS 10.1.1 iPad mini 2 with yalu102, and I erased all content and settings for some weird reason. I didn't backup my device when it had Cydia on it, so now every time I use yalu and press go, it will respring, but there will be no Cydia. It just says "already jailbroken".

I cannot use Cydia Impactor because it says

> Provision.cpp:81 listteams=1102 This Apple ID cannot be used for development with Xcode

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try making another appleID and trying cydia impactor with it. 
And to get cydia you may try wiping your device via iCloud. Probably that would help to get a clean device.